# Arduino pin state (HIGH and LOW voltage range)

Tags: arduino, voltage

When a pin is configured as INPUT and read with *digitalRead*, the HIGH state refers to a voltage >=3V, while a LOW state refers to a voltage =< 1.5V:

[https://docs.particle.io/cards/firmware/language-syntax/variables/#:~:text=When%20a%20pin%20is%20configured,is%20present%20at%20the%20pin.&text=When%20a%20pin%20is%20configured%20to%20OUTPUT%20with%20pinMode%20%2C%20and,pin%20is%20at%203.3%20volts](https://docs.particle.io/cards/firmware/language-syntax/variables/#:%7E:text=When%20a%20pin%20is%20configured,is%20present%20at%20the%20pin.&text=When%20a%20pin%20is%20configured%20to%20OUTPUT%20with%20pinMode%20%2C%20and,pin%20is%20at%203.3%20volts).

Why is the "floating/undefined state" voltage range 1.5V by design, appears to be rather large...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply difficult/expensive to manufacture parts with a very specific voltage limit, and the value of doing so is in reality very low since every digital output will have a similar behavior.

In reality, the inputs will read as either high or low and nothing else, the specification is simply what voltage is needed to guarantee that under all circumstances on all inputs on every device, the input will read as the state you intend.

Probably, most devices will actually switch somewhere in the middle of  the 1.5 to 3 V span, but you won't know exactly when and it will vary with temperature, individual etc.

If you need to switch at a specific voltage, go for an analog comparator based design.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response.

Answer (score 1):

It's wrong. Or not wrong as much as it is simplified. Like much of the Arduino environment, certain facts are obstructified away for beginners. It's easier to say "give it 3V" for a high than saying "Voltage input high minimum voltage is X at Y VDD and Z Temp, maybe".

From the STM32F205RB Arm microcontroller datatsheet, the MCU for a particle board:

[image]

Notice both the low max and high minimum depends on VDD, standard you want to meet (ttl or cmos), tested guaranteed* voltages and theoretical voltages.

All high minimum are much lower than 3V, while the max low voltage is actually lower than the 1.5V you are told. You should be giving 1V or less for a LOW at 3.3V VDD. The range at 3.3V VDD is only about 0.75V theoretical, 1.2V for TTL standard and 1.5V for cmos. But notice CMOS is way less forgiving than the other two. CMOS is also easier and space efficient tech. It's complicated.

**Without getting too much into it**, this is the function of the input gate for both ttl and cmos technology. They are difficult to manufacture in a manner where you have a small, sharp cut off, while also not responding to much to noise. Hysteresis and Schmidt triggers would add alot to the design when it's unneeded in most applications. It's simpler to just say "we are sure at 1V it's low and 1.9V it's a high, don't go in-between if you want accurate results."

***Of course this is based on the microcontroller I found listed for the particle board.*** If a different one was used as the source for the instruction manual, the values will change accordingly.